# 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my HTML page i have a button which on click fetches the elements in the page and passes them on to the server.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="filter_btn" onclick="on_submit()">Submit</button>
```

the function call is handled by my js code like this below.

```
function on_submit()
{
 var $start_date=document.getElementById("datepicker1").value;
 var $end_date=document.getElementById("datepicker2").value;
 var $vid1 = $('#vid1');
 var $vid2 = $('#vid2');
 var $vid1_name = $('#vid1').text();
 var $vid2_name = $('#vid2').text();
 var $metric = $('#metric').val();
 var $frequency = $('#freq').val();
  $.get('../content_focus',{type:"getData",vid1_name:$vid1_name, vid2_name:$vid2_name, vid1:$vid1, vid2:$vid2, start_date:$start_date, end_date:$end_date, metric:$metric, frequency:$frequency}, function(responseData){
  alert('im done');
 });
   }
```

Now the borwer console throws an error stating "'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement."
And none of my print statements or alert statements get executed i would like some help with this

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be the problem is with,

```
 var $vid1 = $('#vid1');
 var $vid2 = $('#vid2');
```

`$vid1` and `$vid2` are HTML elements.

If you want to pass the html use,

```
var $vid1 = $('#vid1').outerHTML();
var $vid2 = $('#vid2').outerHTML();
```

Comment: I think you mean "`$vid1` and `$vid2` are jQuery objects." instead of "`$vid1` and `$vid2` are HTML elements."